# Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. when disposing flutter provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using flutter provider and i was getting

`Provider was used after being disposed`

so i added `context.read<SimpleTeamProvider>().dispose();` in the dispose function after adding this piece of code i start getting this type of error:

```
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method
```

and this is my code

```
class SimpleTeamBody extends StatefulWidget {
const SimpleTeamBody({super.key});

@override
State<SimpleTeamBody> createState() => _SimpleTeamBodyState();
}

class _SimpleTeamBodyState extends State<SimpleTeamBody> with AfterLayoutMixin {
final _controller = ScrollController();
Future<void> loadMedia() async {
final payloadJSON = {
  'service_id': context.read<LayoutProvider>().serviceId,
  'in_carousel': true,
  'team_type': 1
}..removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
await context
    .read<SimpleTeamProvider>()
    .getSimpleTeams(context: context, payload: payloadJSON);
if (context.read<SimpleTeamProvider>().simpleTeams.isNotEmpty) {
  context.read<LayoutProvider>().simpleTeams =
      context.read<SimpleTeamProvider>().simpleTeams;
 }
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
}

@override
void dispose() {
context.read<SimpleTeamProvider>().dispose();
super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 50.h,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: context.watch<SimpleTeamProvider>().apiIsLoading
              ? context.watch<SimpleTeamProvider>().simpleTeams.length + 2
              : context.watch<SimpleTeamProvider>().simpleTeams.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return index >=
                    context.watch<SimpleTeamProvider>().simpleTeams.length
                ? const SimpleTeamLoadingCard()
                : InkWell(
                    onTap: () => {
                      context.push(
                          '${APP_PAGE.teamDetails.toPath}/${context.read<SimpleTeamProvider> 
    ().simpleTeams[index].id}')
                    },
                    child: SimpleTeamCard(
                      imgIcon: context
                              .watch<SimpleTeamProvider>()
                              .simpleTeams[index]
                              .logo ??
                          "",
                    ),
                  );
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}

void _scrollListener() async {
  if (_controller.position.pixels >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
    !context.read<SimpleTeamProvider>().apiIsLoading) {
  await loadMedia();
  }
}

@override
FutureOr<void> afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) async {
await loadMedia();
 }
}
```